# How to create an FTP account for one folder?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have a folder:

`/srv/ftp_folder`

How would one go about setting up an FTP account with upload/download for that folder only with no other access?

Comment: Is this to vague?

Comment: Yes, it is ;) What ftp server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**At first a warning:** Be careful when using FTP, because neither authentication nor data transfer are encrypted.

This information is basically compiled from looking at the manpages and has not been tested, however it should work out that way.

```
$ man vsftpd.conf
```

Append the following lines to your vsftpd configuration:

```
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot.list
```

Then add each user you want to lock to their homedir to the chroot.list file. You can change a users homedir by using

```
$ sudo usermod -d /path/to/homedir user
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was going to say chroot them into their home dirs, but you seem to have beaten me to it. I haven't tested it either but it sounds sane.

Comment: I think this did help! But I ran into an issue where it is giving me this: `500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/srv/ftp_folder/` I also tried chown and chgrp on the ftp_folder but no luck.

Comment: At login time? Have you changed the users homedir to /srv/ftp_folder? Can you verifiy this in /etc/passwd? Have you restarted vsftpd after changing the homedir?